# How to obtain the x and y of where a user clicked java fx

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a application where a user clicks on the screen and we add a circle with a number inside of the circle where the user clicked.

The way I want my application to work is: if I click the screen a pop up comes up asking the user to enter a number. When they press OK, a circle with the number inside of the circle is added to the screen where the user last clicked.

At the moment, I have got the pop up to work and when the user clicks OK a circle is added to the screen but it is not added where the user last clicked. I am not sure how to add the circle where the user last clicked. How would I do this?

Comment: The `MouseEvent` provides methods to get the `x` and `y` coordinates. You can get the coordinates relative to the `Node`, the `Scene`, or the `Screen`. How to position a `Node` at those coordinates will depend on what layout you're using. Try to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you're having so we can see what you're trying to do as code.

Answer (score 0):

As Slaw pointed out in his comment, you can get the X/Y coordinates of a mouse click from the `MouseEvent`.

So create an `onMouseClicked()` method for whichever node you allow the user to click on.

The following MCVE will demonstrate by printing out the X/Y coordinates whenever you click on the root `VBox` container:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Add a listener to catch MouseEvents when clicking on the root VBox
        root.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("X: " + mouseEvent.getX());
            System.out.println("Y: " + mouseEvent.getY());
        });

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```